# Automatic Edit text with country code splited and mobile number

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

i want to show my edit text user will enter 13 number and it make first two number as country code and after mobile number that should look like:-

```
+ 12 -3456789102
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all have a layout like this..

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_country_codes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">

                </Spinner>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Mobile number here.."
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

and next if you have a list of country codes with you like this...

```
String arr_country_codes[]={"+92","+95","+96","+02"};
```

populate it to spinner as follows..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arr_country_codes);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_country_codes.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and selected item will get as follows..

```
String cnt_code_and_mbl_no="";
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        sp_country_codes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                builder.append(arr_country_codes[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

and total text will be get on clicking some button. Here we will append string from edittext to previous spinner selected item and copy it to string as follows..

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            builder.append("<space>"+editText.getText().toString().trim());
            cnt_code_and_mbl_no = builder.toString();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

or else you can dynamically check it and can add spaces using TextWatcher like this...

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  String content = s.toString();
                  if (content.length()==15)
                  {
                      cnt_code_and_mbl_no=content;//storing value in global variable for future use
                  }
                  else if (content.length()==1 || content.length()==4)
                  {
                      editText.setText(s+" ");//whenever types + or + 12, we add some space after it
                  }
                  //after + 12 , the user should enter 10 characters itself, so the total length is 15
                  else if (content.length()>15)
                  {
                      editText.setText(cnt_code_and_mbl_no);
                  }
            }
        });
```